# SUP101: blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sybase, sup

I've been following the SUP101 tutorial for both IPhone and Blackberry.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01208.0152/doc/html/vhu1236620712162.html

I managed to make both work.

But, when I tried to launch the SUP101 tutorial for Blackberry on a device I keep getting the following message :

SUP101Output: Module 'sup_client_rim' not found.

I managed to launch tutorial and simple apps on the blackberry but not SUP101 that have extra jar and COD

I think what is happening is that BB plugin for eclipse is not adding the libraries (in the tutorial we have to manually copy the cod files into the simulator)

has anybody got an idea how to solve this?
or does anybody have a good link on how to test on device?

Best regards

Jason Rogers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out after a bit of trial and error

The SUP are only used to allow you to compile the project

To actually run it on the device, you need to install the .alx files

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on SUP platform for a little longer. I have faced the similar issue. Can u tell me which SUP version you are using and which BB SDK you are build? SO i may able to trace.

I have faced the same problem, and after a long trace i found that the Source code i was generating using SUP, was not compatible with the jar file i was using. I have struggled to manage that by checking the jad compatibility and then with various BB SDK versions. Later realized that it was with versions.

Also, in build path make sure you are selecting all of the jar files in order and exports and take it one level above the RIM library. Sure it will work.